# How to add array of objects in react state hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

From the API i have fetched the data in the following format

{ teamsregistered:
[ { paid: false,
_id: 602dea67451db71e71e4babd,
name: 'MOH',
mobile: '+919566879683',
tag: 'JAR1NAH',
__v: 0 },
{ paid: false,
_id: 602deb602924a41fb0c88415,
name: 'RAJ',
mobile: '+919566879683',
tag: 'JAR1NAH',
__v: 0 },
{ paid: false,
_id: 602deb692924a41fb0c88416,
name: 'two',
mobile: '+919566879683',
tag: 'JAR1NAH',
__v: 0 } ],
rounds: [],
table: [],
ongoinground: 0,
status: 'not completed',
totalamount: '0',
_id: 602dea4d451db71e71e4babb,
name: 'ATD',
tag: 'JAR1NAH',
date: '2021-02-25T18:30:00.000Z',
__v: 0 }

In this teams registered is a array of Objects .i need to store the array of objects in a state hook and need an access to every element in it and also i need send the data to another component,

```
.then(response => {
        console.log(response.teamsregistered) //it shows correct output
        setData({...data,
            name:response.name,
            date:response.date,
            ongoinground:response.ongoinground,
            status:response.status,
            teamsregistered:response.teamsregistered
        })
       console.log(data.teamsregistered) // it shows "undefined"
```

when i run console.log(data.teamsregistered) it shows 'undefined'.how to set in the state hook and acces every element in it.

Comment: State changes are asynchronous, you can't `console.log` them on the next line. Print the state in the main body of the function to see latest value

Comment: Try something like this `console.log(data?.teamsregistered)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when i run console.log(data.teamsregistered) it shows 'undefined'.how to set in the state hook and acces every element in it.

This is happing because [`setState()` hook is asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately). So if you want to see the update you have to use `useEffect()` Hook to see the update in the state
like:-

```
.then(response => {
        console.log(response.teamsregistered) //it shows correct output
        setData({...data,
            name:response.name,
            date:response.date,
            ongoinground:response.ongoinground,
            status:response.status,
            teamsregistered:response.teamsregistered
        })
useEffect(() => { console.log(data.teamsregistered) }, [data])
```